# All joysticks as "DragonRise Inc. Generic USB joystick"

Tags: usb, gamepad, joystick

I have two joysticks.
Both of them are detected in Ubuntu as "DragonRise Inc. Generic USB Joystick".
And their second axis (the right stick) is detected as part of the first axis, and works erratically. Also some applications, such as some emulators fail to detect them in any way.

One is a 3GC SteelSeries Rumble Controller, and the other one is generic.
I don't know what to do, as I need them for my job.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that there are driver issues, further work may need to be done reverse engineering the devices, they have never worked 100% and recently got worse.

There have been no developments for the drivers for many years, but there are a few mentions of this problem in 2015 (Youtube, Debian bug) so perhaps Steam is helping draw attention to these devices.

I found `jstest-gtk` a nice utility when checking these things out, my experiences with Xbox compatible controllers is very good, but I'm looking for a more PSX style one myself.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I found a solution. The app [jstest-gtk](https://flathub.org/apps/details/io.gitlab.jstest_gtk.jstest_gtk) allows you to check the inputs of your controller. I strongly suggest anyone who has this problem download it to check how your device is working.

In the case of this particular joystick (mine is also a dragonrise inc), the horizontal movement of the first stick activates two different axis: Axis 0 and Axis 2. While the vertical movement of the second stick also activates two axis: Axis 2 and Axis 4. As you can see, both sticks are activating Axis 2. Most likely, the software you're trying to connect to is recognizing axis 2 rather than 0 and 4. In that case, you can go to the configurations of that particular software and change the axis it's using.

In my case, it was Dolphin. In the configuration screen of the controller I was able to manually change 'Axis 2' to Axis 0 and 4.